# CGGetOnlineDisplayList usage in Swift (array as a parameter)

Tags: arrays, macos, swift, parameters

Below is my Swift code so far. Unfortunately the array onlineDspys doesn't get updated by CGGetOnlineDisplayList. Help appreciated.

#### main.swift

```
import Foundation
import CoreGraphics
 
var mainID = CGMainDisplayID()
 
println("ID is \(mainID)")
 
var dErr: CGError
let maxDisplays: UInt32 = 16
var onlineDspys: [CGDirectDisplayID] = [mainID]
var dspyCnt: UInt32 = 0
 
dErr = CGGetOnlineDisplayList(maxDisplays, &onlineDspys, &dspyCnt)
 
println("dspyCnt is \(dspyCnt)")
 
for currentDisplay in onlineDspys {
  println("currentDisplay is \(currentDisplay)")
  println("CGDisplayPixelsHigh(currentDisplay) is \(CGDisplayPixelsHigh(currentDisplay))")
  println("CGDisplayPixelsWide(currentDisplay) is \(CGDisplayPixelsWide(currentDisplay))")
}
```

Comment: What *does* `CGGetOnlineDisplayList` do?

Comment: see   https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/Quartz_Services_Ref/

Comment: What values do `dErr` and `dspyCnt` have?  Also, what's wrong with your keyboard which cause all of these weird vrblNms?

Comment: Vwls cst $250. :-)

Answer (score 5):

There are a couple issues here that are misleading you into believing that your `onlineDspys` array is not being updated.

The first problem is that you're actually pre-populating the first index of that array with the exact value that the `CGGetOnlineDisplayList` method call would set it to.  If you instead prepopulated it with a value like `0`, you'd see it's filling it in:

```
var onlineDspys: [CGDirectDisplayID] = [0]
```

The second problem is that `CGGetOnlineDisplayList` won't allocate memory for us.  It can't call `append` on our array.  We have to give it a block of memory to fill in the values.  So, when we set up the variables we're going to pass in to the the function, we need to set them up more like this:

```
let maxDisplays: UInt32 = 16
var onlineDisplays = [CGDirectDisplayID](count: Int(maxDisplays), repeatedValue: 0)
var displayCount: UInt32 = 0
```

Now, our `onlineDisplays` is an array full of 16 zeros for `CGGetOnlineDisplayList` to fill in.

We call the function:

```
let dErr = CGGetOnlineDisplayList(maxDisplays, & onlineDisplays, & displayCount)
```

Now, the tricky bit... we don't want to waste time iterating over the parts of the array that didn't get filled in, so we make use of what the function filled into the `displayCount` variable:

```
for currentDisplay in onlineDisplays[0..<Int(displayCount)] {
    print("currentDisplay is \(currentDisplay)")
    print("CGDisplayPixelsHigh(currentDisplay) is \(CGDisplayPixelsHigh(currentDisplay))")
    print("CGDisplayPixelsWide(currentDisplay) is \(CGDisplayPixelsWide(currentDisplay))")
}
```

---

The whole code snippet all together:

```
import Foundation
import CoreGraphics

var mainID = CGMainDisplayID()

print("ID is \(mainID)")

let maxDisplays: UInt32 = 16
var onlineDisplays = [CGDirectDisplayID](count: Int(maxDisplays), repeatedValue: 0)
var displayCount: UInt32 = 0

let dErr = CGGetOnlineDisplayList(maxDisplays, &onlineDisplays, &displayCount)

print("dspyCnt is \(displayCount)")

for currentDisplay in onlineDisplays[0..<Int(displayCount)] {
    print("currentDisplay is \(currentDisplay)")
    print("CGDisplayPixelsHigh(currentDisplay) is \(CGDisplayPixelsHigh(currentDisplay))")
    print("CGDisplayPixelsWide(currentDisplay) is \(CGDisplayPixelsWide(currentDisplay))")
}
```

Comment: Here it worked but I had to change the onlineDisplays line to:
`var onlineDisplays = [CGDirectDisplayID](repeating: 0, count: Int(maxDisplays))`

Comment: in case you want to dynamically adjust for those extreme cases when you have more than 16 displays, use `var maxDisplays: UInt32 = 0` and
`CGGetOnlineDisplayList(0, nil, &maxDisplays)` before initializing `onlineDisplays`